# SysUtils.LoadPackage replaces Aplication.OnMessage handler

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a main form where I set a handler for the `Application.OnMessage` event. (Code of this handler is placed in the main form). Then, while running the program, there can be calls to `SysUtils.LoadPackage` that loads some bpl-package. And after that is loaded, the handler of `Application.OnMessage` is changed.

I couldn't find what doing this. At least there is not right such code that goes `Application.OnMessage :=` in the package.

One more thing: in the debugger, before LoadPackage, I see OnMessage handler described as `Main.TMainForm.AppMessage`. All other handlers (such as OnMinimize, OnModalBegin e.t.c.) are nil. And after LoadPackage all events have handlers, described as `Vcl.AppEvnts.TMultiCaster.DoMessage`.

Comment: The package implements its own Application.Onmessage handler perhaps? How can we know without knowing what is in either your application or the bpl.

Comment: Well, the obvious thing is that there is code in the package that you loaded that does `Application.OnMessage := ...` and it's pretty hard to imagine that it could be anything else. I mean, how else do you imagine that a property changes?

Comment: well. maybe, but I couldn't find what doing this. At least there is not right such code that goes `Application.OnMessage :=` at the package. One more thing: in debugger before LoadPackage I see OnMessage handler descrived as `Main.TMainForm.AppMessage`. All other handlers (such as OnMinimize, OnModalBegin e.t.c.) are equal to nil. And after LoadPackage  all methods has handlers and desribed as `Vcl.AppEvnts.TMultiCaster.DoMessage`.

Comment: Including unit `AppEvents` will through unit's initialization create a `TMultiCaster`, which assigns handlers to (some or all?) `TApplication` events.

Comment: Set a breakpoint just after InitControls in vcl.controls.initialization. Run application. When the breakpoint is hit, set a data breakpoint for Application.FOnMessage. Run (resume) again. When the data breakpoint is hit, examine the code.

Comment: If you won't show a [mcve], then you will need to remove this post (because it cannot be answered) and debug your program yourself.

Comment: Why cannot? Mr. @nil gave right clue. Indeed adding `vcl.AppEvnts` to uses causes this behavoiur.

Comment: Because this question wouldn't be useful for future readers, which is pretty much what SO is all about. Any answer would be based on guesses, and that's not how we work. We work on facts, and facts require an MCVE.

Comment: That unit contains the TApplicationEvents component, which can be used to assign application events at designtime. Because you could use multiple components, I think the unit attaches its own event handler, which then forwards any events to the event handlers assigned to all the TApplicationEvent components. It would be nice, of course, if it kept track of existing handlers, because if every bpl is going to do the same trick again, that also implies that TApplicationEvents wouldn't work well at all in applications with multiple packages...

Comment: Can you try adding `Vcl.AppEvnts` to the main application too?

Comment: @GolezTrol you are right that `TApplicationEvents` is a multicaster, it delegates `TApplication` events to every `TApplicationEvents` instance, allowing multiple Forms, components, etc to receive the same app events without stepping on each other's toes trying to assign handlers to `TApplication` directly. So yes, the solution to the OP's issue is to add `TApplicationEvents` to the `MainForm`.

Comment: Yes. Just including  the unit in the main application should do the trick already, because that will assign the multicaster before you assign your own event handler. But assigning your own will overwrite the one assigned by the multicaster, so I agree it's cleaner to use a TApplicationEvents in the main application too. (All this is assuming that Vcl.AppEvnts Initialize won't fire again when the package is loaded, but I don't think it will, although I must admin my experience with runtime packages is limited.)

Answer (score 5):

The package in question uses an internal instance of `TApplicationEvents`, which is a multicaster that intercepts `TApplication` events and delegates them to every `TApplicationEvents` instance in the application, allowing multiple Forms, components, etc to receive the same app events without stepping on each other's toes trying to assign handlers to `TApplication` directly.

So, to coexist with the package, the solution is to add a `TApplicationEvents` to your `MainForm` and assign a handler to its `OnMessage` event, instead of assigning a handler to the `TApplication.OnMessage` event directly.